# How to unit test the Refit ApiResponse<T>?

Tags: c#, rest, unit-testing, refit

I'm using refit to call APIs and the response is wrapped in `ApiResonse<T>`. I can mock the refit call that returns a mocked `ApiResponse<T>` and assert. Everything works as it should except I'm not sure how I can test the api call that returns an exception.

```
[Get("/customer/{id}")]
Task<ApiResponse<Customer>> GetCustomer(int id);
```

It seems if `ApiResponse<T>` is used Refit wraps all the exceptions that happens inside the request into `ApiException` and attaches to `ApiResponse<T>`.  If `Task<T>` is used instead, catching the `ApiException` is the responsibility of the caller.

I created the `ApiException` with `ApiException.Create()` but not sure where to put that in the `ApiResponse<T>`.  The last parameter to the `Create()` method is ApiException but the exception I create and set doesn't show up in the ApiResponse at all and therefore can't test.

```
var apiResponse = new ApiResponse<Customer>(
    new HttpResponseMessage(BadRequest),
    null,
    null,
    await ApiException.Create(,,,Exception("Something bad happened inside the api")
 );
```

I can't get the `Something bad happened...` message in the unit test but just the 'Bad Request' message.  Am I unit testing the ApiResponse in refit right? Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know Refit, but according to their docs I'd expect the following two options:

## Return `ApiResponse<Customer>`

Let's take a look at your code (which is not correct C#, by the way - please provide correctly working code):

```cs
var apiResponse = new ApiResponse<Customer>(
    new HttpResponseMessage(BadRequest),
    null,
    null,
    await ApiException.Create(,,,Exception("Something bad happened inside the api")
 );
```

When executing this code, Refit is instructed to return exactly what you ask for: *return `HTTP 500` with the following inner exception*.

So I'd expect you'll find *Something bad happened inside the api* inside `apiResponse.Error`, but no exception will be thrown.

## Throw `ApiException`

Since `ApiException` derives from `System.Exception`, you can replace this

```cs
var apiResponse = new ApiResponse<Customer>(
    new HttpResponseMessage(BadRequest),
    null,
    null,
    await ApiException.Create(,,,Exception("Something bad happened inside the api")
 );
```

by

```cs
throw await ApiException.Create("Something bad happened inside the api", message, method, response, settings);
```

Now you can catch your exception inside your unit test.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Sorry I will update my code with the correct c# code.  I didn't have access to the code when I opened this question.  Your suggestion may work but I was hoping for moq or something that does that automatically replicating the actual refit behavior.  In the end I ended up with just using the `Task<T>` instead of `ApiResponse<T>`.  I'm just catching the apiexception in the code.